# Access Control to restrict view to pages

Tags: mediawiki, access-control, mediawiki-extensions

I don't find MediaWiki a user-friendly and easy-to-customise tool but probably just because I'm new to it. What I need to do is to have some pages visible to:

- anyone
- registered users only, and
- a certain group of users.

Even if in the documentation it is well specified that MediaWiki does not support this usage, I've found an extension that seems to do it ([Access Control](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AccessControl)) but I have a problem in using that. I'd like to use MediaWiki groups and I'm trying to make some pages visible only to `bureaucrat`. I don't understand how to put the `<accesscontrol> bureaucrat </accesscontrol>` tag. If I put it in the page content (via normal editing page wiki procedure) it does not seems to be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found another extension, named [Restrict access by category and group](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aRestrict_access_by_category_and_group). It works like a charm, nice and simple documentation, easy to use. And.. it seems to work!